Can I replace a straight grease fitting with an angled?
Having successfully used a grease gun for the first time in my life, I found a grease fitting on my little tractor with too little clearance for my grease gun tip, and one that needs replacing.
When I searched for generic spare parts I found not only "normal" fittings but also 45° and 90° angled, such as these (image from the cheap-and-cheerful Swedish store Jula):

My question may seem trivial but I wonder if I can simply replace the straight hard-to-reach grease fitting with an angled version with no side effects?
They seem mechanically more complex so maybe they are prone to failure? On the other hand it seems like these grease fittings are designed to be replaced so it's probably not critical.

Yes. There's no problem to replace the grease nipples with an angled one, or even a different type.
The important parameter is the threads that enter the part. Common threads are BSF, NPT and metric threads. Within each of those there's different dimensions. You'll have to figure out which thread type and size is appropriate.

Thanks, there's no mention of the threads in the manual, but I'm going to assume metric as a start since it's a Finnish machine sold in Sweden. Of course I'll double check once the old nipple is removed!

Don't assume. Even on European machines imperial fittings are rather normal.
